# Center a sentence on one line CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a sentence in the middle of the page. This is the code I came up with:

```
#wiz {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', sans-serif;
    top: 250px;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%
}
```

This centers the txt but puts each word on top of the other instead of on one line. I tried adding height, width and then margin but I couldent get it to work.

How would I do this?

Comment: You're adding `left` and `right` positioning, effectively making your `#wiz` element zero-width.

Comment: Check out this page: https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This in your code:

```
left: 50%;
right: 50%
```

causes that element to have zero width: The left border is 50% from the left side, the right border is 50% from the right side. Remaining space: 0

Just erase these two, `text-align: center;` is sufficient...

P.S.: Since position is absolute, you'll need to define a width, go for 100%. (or use `position:relative;` instead)

Answer (score 0):

`left: 50%; right: 50%` — if the left edge is half way across the container and the right side is half way across the container, then the width of your box is going to be `0` and the content will word wrap at the earlier opportunity.

Remove `position`, `top`, `left`, and `right`. If the element isn't a block by default, add `display: block`.

Consider replacing `top` with `margin-top`.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
#wiz {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', sans-serif;
    top: 250px;
    width: 100%;
```

}
The `width` attribute will make you container the same width as it's parent container. The `text-align` attribute will center the text. The `left` and `right` attributes are trying to make the #wiz container be 50% from each side giving an effective width of 0 which is forcing the text to stack.